# Por que Arrays implementa IEnumerable mas não implementa IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, array, genéricos, enumerable

Estava fazendo uma classe que contém um Array da classe `Episode`:

```cs
public Episode[] EpisodesList;
```

Aí implementei o `IEnumerable<T>` na minha classe. E como esperado, implementei o método `GetEnumerator()`...

```cs
        public IEnumerator<Episode> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ((IEnumerable<Episode>)this.EpisodesList).GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
```

No entanto, não funciona sem o *casting*...

Mas só implementando o `IEnumerable` (sem ser o `IEnumerable<T>`), funciona normal, sem *casting*:

```cs
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.EpisodesList.GetEnumerator();
    }
```

Por que isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Array* definitivamente implementa `IEnumerable<T>`.
Experimente fazer

```
bool isIEnumerableGeneric = EpisodesList is IEnumerable<Episode>
```

e verá que o resultado é `true`.

A razão do comportamento que descreve deve-se, segundo eu entendi da [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx), é que a implementação só é "disponibilizada" (*provided*) em tempo de execução e por isso a *interface* genérica não aparece na *"declaration syntax"* da classe *Array*.

Trecho retirado da documentação:

> Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, the Array class implements the System.Collections.Generic.IList, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection, and System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable generic interfaces. **The implementations are provided to arrays at run time, and as a result, the generic interfaces do not appear in the declaration syntax for the Array class**. In addition, there are no reference topics for interface members that are accessible only by casting an array to the generic interface type (explicit interface implementations). The key thing to be aware of when you cast an array to one of these interfaces is that members which add, insert, or remove elements throw NotSupportedException.

Que traduzindo para o português é:

> A partir do .NET Framework 2.0, a classe Array implementa as interfaces genéricas System.Collections.Generic.IList, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection e System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable. **As implementações são disponibilizadas para os arrays em tempo de execução, e como resultado, as interfaces genéricas não aparecem na sintaxe de declaração da classe Array**. Adicionalmente, não há tópicos referenciados para membros de interface que são acessíveis apenas ao efetuar-se *cast* de um array para um tipo interface genérico (implementações explícitas de interface). O importante é estar atento que quando você efetua o *cast* de um array para uma destas interface é que os memebros que adicionam, inserem, ou removem elementos lançam NotSupportedException.

Comment: Tomei a liberdade de adicionar uma tradução do trecho em inglês, caso não se importe.

Comment: De modo algum. Assim ficou mais completa.